# Parse Automatic User and Subclasses

Tags: parse-platform

I'm having problems with the Automatic User setting in my parse project.

I have a subclass of `PFUser` called `GLUser` which properly follows the subclassing guide in the documentation. After adding some initialization code in the `+object` method to set some default fields, I also enabled automatic user on `PFUser`. Now, it seems like my `+user` method is not being called when parse creates a new anonymous `PFUser` in response to a call to `currentUser`. Is this intentional or am I doing something wrong?

I could work around this pretty easily, but I wanted to check first.

Comment: Did you call `registerClass` on GLUser?

Comment: Yep, like I said, I have no errors and everything else is working fine, it's just that my object method isn't being run when parse creates a new automatic anonymous user in response to a call to `currentUser`.

Answer (score 0):

When subclassing a PFUser, you have to include an underscore in the expected function 'parseClassName'!

```
+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return @"_User";
}
```

Comment: Note that this only needs to be done for PFUser and not for any other PFObject subclassing

Comment: [This](https://www.parse.com/questions/subclass-pfuser) post on the parse pages say you don't, so are you sure about this?

Comment: 100%. I had to do it for all my apps and all of them use it to date without incident.

Comment: Parse, alas, doesn't update their docs as often as they should -- the link above is 2 years old it seems!!

Comment: I haven't had time to try it yet - porting all my code to swift

Comment: Oh sweet! Let me know :)

Comment: I ended up coming back to this via a google search on another project I was working on where I had the exact same problem... looked through parse code, and when the annon user is instantiated, `[PFUser user]` is called, so no chance of my subclass getting the message. (even if I implement the parseClassName method, which is not needed since `PFUser` implements it anyways

Comment: Did you also implement `+ (void)load {
    [self registerSubclass];
}`

Comment: Calling it through app delegate. Here is the issue I made in the parse repo https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/463

Comment: Post more of your code? I have since done this several times in Swift & Objective-C with no issues -- hopefully I can help!

Comment: I'm not having problems subclassing the `PFUser` object, its just that I'm not getting a chance to set my subclass up. You can see the response in the link above from parse dev saying that there is not a guaranteed init method that will be called, apart from `init`, and you can't modify the object in that method